# Unable to uninstall a plug in from Eclipse

Tags: javascript, eclipse, pydev

I am trying to uninstall a plug in (PyDev) from Eclipse Neon 3.  I think it was installed incorrectly (since it wasn't showing up) so i wanted to uninstall and re-install but uninstall button is grayed out and i can't uninstall this plug in.  When I tried to uninstall it via marketplace, it

> "PyDev for Eclipse" cannot be fully uninstalled because other installed software requires it.  The parts that are not required will be uninstalled.

and i dont see any other software that requires pydev.

Please help, thank you.

Comment: See _Help > About Eclipse IDE: Installation Details_. Whatever, Eclipse Neon is more than six years and 20 releases behind. Better get a fresh installation.

Comment: Eclipse 2023-03 is due to be released tomorrow (15th March) this is 21 releases old newer that Neon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you proceed to uninstall, does it leave anything behind? As a note,if you really need an older version of Eclipse you should use older versions of PyDev, python and java too.

See: https://www.pydev.org/manual_101_install.html#need-to-use-older-eclipse-java-python for details.

Comment: didnt know python had to be an old version too, thank you!